# Нейросеть перестаёт работать при помещении обращения к ней в поток сервера, написаннного на питоне

Tags: многопоточность, нейронные-сети, python-3.6

Ниже приведён текст на питоне, который работает. Он подаёт вход на сохранённую в файле нейросеть.

```
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import traceback
from threading import Thread
import errno
from socket import error as socket_error
from datetime import datetime

# сохранение модели
from keras.models import model_from_json
import h5py
p= [8e-05, 5e-05, 8e-05, 9e-05, 1e-05, -4e-05, 2e-05, -1e-05, 9e-05,
0.00011, 0.0001, 0.00016, 0.00022, 0.00019, 0.00021, -2e-05, 0.00014,
0.0, 8e-05, 2e-05, 5e-05, 7e-05, -0.00015, -0.00017, -0.00018,
5e-05, 7e-05, 5e-05, 5e-05, 1e-05, 0.0, -2e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 7e-05,
-1e-05, 7e-05, 1e-05, 0.00015, 5e-05, 5e-05, 7e-05, 0.00012,
8e-05, -6e-05, -0.00016, -0.00021, -0.00014, -0.00011, 4e-05,
-5e-05, 1e-05, -7e-05, -3e-05, 8e-05, -1e-05, 0.00022, 0.00032,
0.00017, 0.00029, 2e-05, 0.00021, -0.00017, -0.00011, -0.00011,
0.00015, 0.00025, 0.00028, 0.00021, 7e-05, 0.00013, -7e-05, -7e-05,
-0.00019, -0.00017, -0.00019, -0.00014, -0.00019, -0.00015, -1e-05,
7e-05, 2e-05, 1e-05, -1e-05, 1e-05, 0.0, 7e-05, 0.00018, 0.00011,
0.00015, 4e-05, 0.00011, -5e-05, -7e-05, -1e-05, 2e-05]

MainModelDir="K:\\MT5\Python\\"
CurModelDir="model 1 min -c\\"
ModelFile=MainModelDir+CurModelDir+"model.json"
WeightFile=MainModelDir+CurModelDir+"model.h5"
print(ModelFile,"  ",WeightFile);

def ModelFromJson(ModelFile,WeightFile):
  # load json and create model
  json_file = open(ModelFile, 'r')
  loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
  json_file.close()
  loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
  # load weights into new model
  loaded_model.load_weights(WeightFile)
  print("Loaded model from disk")
  return loaded_model

model=ModelFromJson(ModelFile,WeightFile)
pp=np.reshape(p,(1,len(p)))
pp=np.asarray(pp)
print("pp=",pp)
u=model.predict(pp,batch_size=1)
print("u=",u)
```

Как только я перемещаю эти операции в thread сервера, получаю ошибку при обращении
    u=model.predict(pp,batch_size=1)

Нейросеть та же самая. Входные данные из того же источника.
Текст ошибки (самый конец оч длинного сообщения):
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
Эта маленькая программка написана специально для поиска ошибки, но в ней нет ошибок, которые проявляются в основной программе.
Конец сообщения

Comment: На github и stackoverflow никто ничего о причинах не сказал.
НО была рекомендация вернуться к 1.5.- впоследствии помогло.
Зато прочитал огромное количество жалоб аналогичного характера.
Заработала одна из программ после downgrade до 1.5 или 1.4.
Вторая - сервер, использующий нейросеть, попрежнему не работала.
Проблема решилась неожиданно с помощью танца с бубном.
Прежде чем запускать сервер, я подал на вход нейросети
один, в общем то случайно выбранный массив.
Его значение было непосредственно вписано в программу.
После этого успешно заработал и сервер.